# How do you mock an external npm module with Jest?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm attempting to mock an npm module that is not being referenced in the test file.  Most of the answers that I've seen have been where a mock is created in the test file and then referenced also from the test file.  That is not what I'm trying to do.

I would like my test to mock an npm module and have the function `testMe` to attempt to call code from the module that is mocked and receive mock data from it.  This has for some reason proved to be elusive.

`image.ts`

```
import Jimp from "jimp/es";

export const testMe = async (string: string) => {
  const res = await Jimp.read(string);

  return res;
}
```

`image.test.ts`

```
import { testMe } from '../src/utils/image';

jest.mock('jimp/es', () => ({
  read: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('mockedString'))
}));

describe('testMe', () => {
  it('successfully completes', async () => {
    const image = 'abcde==';

    const result = await testMe(image);

    expect(result).toBe('mockedString');
  });
});
```

How am I supposed to construct the test file to properly mock the dependency?  Currently, I only receive an error of:

```
  ● testMe › successfully completes

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'read' of undefined

      21 | 
      22 | export const testMe = async (string: string) => {
    > 23 |   const res = await Jimp.read(string);
         |                          ^
      24 | 
      25 |   return res;
      26 | }

      at Object.exports.testMe (src/utils/image.ts:23:26)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/image.test.ts:26:26)
```

Comment: Actually your code above should work. [I've set it up here with js](https://repl.it/repls/ScratchySingleDebugging)

Comment: @Teneff Wow you're right.  I guess I have something configured incorrectly in my jest.config.ts which I'll try to narrow down.